# Sitecore Usergroup Deutschland (Bremen) - April 04, 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

## Details

- When: April 04, 2017. 13:00 to 17:30 CET (11:00 - 15:30 UTC)
- Where: Hotel Überfluss, Bremen, Germany
- Event page and signup: https://www.xing.com/events/sitecore-usergroup-deutschland-bremen-1783066

## Brief (German)

Die Sitecore Usergroup Deutschland trifft sich zum zweiten Mal im Jahr 2017! Für dieses Treffen am 04. April 2017 gehen wir dieses Mal direkt in die Nähe von Sitecore, nach Bremen!

Die Vorträge sind aktuell noch in den Planungen, meldet euch aber schon mal an oder sagt schon zu - dann bekommt ihr alle Updates dieser Seite mit!

Liebe Grüße, das Orga Team

Unsere Ziele:

Eine regelmäßige Veranstaltung zum gemeinsamen Erfahrungsaustausch über die Sitecore Experience Platform
Gemeinsam organisierte Veranstaltung
Präsentationen über interessante und neue Möglichkeiten
Gemeinsamer Wissensaustausch
Get-Together
Zielgruppen:

Entwickler
Online Marketing Mitarbeiter
Entscheider
Jeder der mehr über Sitecore wissen möchte
Ich denke ein Austausch unter allen Beteiligten fördert das Wissen anderer Bereiche und so ebenfalls der Verständnis der anderen Komponenten. Daher möchten wir niemanden ausschließen und versuchen für alle Beteiligten eine gute Mischung der Themen zu erreichen.

Was es nicht ist:

Die Usergroup ist nicht der Platz für Kundengespräche
Die Usergroup ist nicht dafür da neue Kunden zu gewinnen
Die Usergroup ist unabhängig
Es ist keine Werbeveranstaltung

Es ist ein gemeinschaftlich organisiertes Event ohne jegliche Gewinnabsichten, jegliche Einnahmen werden vollständig wieder in die Usergroup investiert.

Die Entscheidung über die Themen und Richtung erfolgt ebenfalls gemeinsam.

Wir möchten einen Platz zum Erfahrungsaustausch für alle Sitecore-Interessenten erschaffen - wie gesagt, Partner- und Kunden-unabhängig.

Wir freuen uns auf ein interessantes Event und den Austausch der Erfahrungen mit Sitecore.

## Speakers

- Yevgeniy Fridman
- Axel Pötsch
- Philipp Nestler
- Arne Hutfilter
- Henrink Breum Andersen

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins in 3 days.